# Unable to create a constant value of type 'X.Models.Game'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got a complex query written in **SQL** which works.

```
SELECT  Instruments.Id as [Id], Instruments.ShareCode as [Share Code], Instruments.Name AS [Short Name], Instruments.Description as [Share Name], 
            InstrumentGames.Instrument_Id, 
            InstrumentGames.Game_Id, Games.Name AS [Game Name], 
            Entries.Name AS [Entry Name], AspNetUsers.UserName,  AspNetUsers.Id as [User_Id],
            Sectors.Name AS Sector_Id, Sectors.ShortName AS Sector
FROM    AspNetUsers INNER JOIN
            Entries ON AspNetUsers.Id = Entries.User_Id INNER JOIN
            Games ON Entries.Game_Id = Games.Id INNER JOIN
            InstrumentGames ON Games.Id = InstrumentGames.Game_Id INNER JOIN
            Instruments ON InstrumentGames.Instrument_Id = Instruments.Id INNER JOIN
            Sectors ON Instruments.Sector_Id = Sectors.Id
WHERE Instruments.Listed = 'true' and InstrumentGames.Game_Id = 2 and Entries.User_Id = 'd28d6552-7d98-476c-82cb-063e7ef45cb6'
```

I'm using Entity code first models and trying to convert what I have in SQL to a **linq query**.
I've come up with:

```
public static Models.Instrument GetShare(string shareSearchCriteria, 
    Models.Game selectedGame, 
    string userId)
{
    var _db = new JSEChallenge.Models.ApplicationDbContext();
    var records = (from instru in _db.Instruments
                   from e in _db.Entries
                   where (instru.ShareCode.Contains(shareSearchCriteria) ||
                        instru.Name.Contains(shareSearchCriteria) ||
                        instru.Description.Contains(shareSearchCriteria))
                   where (instru.Listed == true &&
                   instru.Games.Contains(selectedGame) &&
                   e.User_Id == userId)
                   select instru).ToList();
    return records.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But I keep getting this **error**:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'X.Models.Game'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

I think the issue is the m2m table `InstrumentGames`. In my SQL query I can join it easily but in my C# I cannot. The way I usually find m2m records is syntax like `instru.Games.Contains(selectedGame)`

Unfortunately I still cannot get this to work.

How do I implement this kind of query in Linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will work, but try instru.Games.Any(q => q.Id == selectedGame.Id) instead of instru.Games.Contains(selectedGame).

Hope this helps!